# How to throw an ajax error with ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I want to handle all server-side errors with jQuery on client side. For this purpose a create axception handling attrbute for my MVC3 application like this:

```
public class JsonErrorHandlerAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string result = jsSerializer.Serialize(new { error = filterContext.Exception.Message });
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(result);
    }
}
```

But with this approach it just returns normal json response with 200 OK result. A don't want to parse it on client side to determine if it has an error or not. So my question is what is the best way to throw an ajax error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your function

```
HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
```

This will raise the error event if you use jQuery ajax, there you can react.

Comment: Be sure to use the right code - using 500 as a blanket "something bad happened" return is bad practice. Here is a list of status codes: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html Selecting the right one in the right situation is important.

Comment: @Fourth: Thx, you're right, that should be considered! But to keep it simple the 500 is ok I think.